# Make 2 videos on top of each other in a 1080×1920 scene

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to make two videos on top of each other. Right now i am scaling both to 1080x960 using ffmpeg and putting them together using vstack. Unfortunetely no success. Can anyone help me?

```
  ffmpeg()
      .input('./placeholder.mp4').videoCodec('copy')
      .input("./scaled_YT.mp4").videoCodec('copy')
      .complexFilter([
        `[0:v]scale=1080x960[v0];[1:v]scale=1080x960[v1];[v0][v1]vstack=inputs=2[v]`
    ], ['v'])
      .toFormat('mp4')
      .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Files have been merged!');
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
          console.error('Error:', err)
      })
      .save(outputPath);
```

```
Error: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: 
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Discord Bots\TEMP_TEST\done_projects\videoEditor_bot\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:182:22)  
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with a simpler ffmpeg operation?  Also, what library are you using?